# How can I get a Netty server to reload a TLS certificate when it is renewed?

Tags: java, ssl, netty, aleph

I have a Netty-based server that uses PEM-encoded certificate files that are periodically re-issued (by Let's Encrypt). Netty fully supports loading the PEM crypto material, but when the certificate (.cer file) is later re-issued, the server needs to be restarted to see it.

I have handled this up until now by adding a custom channel init handler to add the logic to reload the cert and add an appropriate SSLHandler built from that. But now I'm wanting to use Aleph, and it expects a Netty SSLContext object for TLS.

This seems like a topical and general problem with the growing popularity of Let's Encrypt and its relatively short-lived certs, and I'd like to solve it properly. Which means a Netty-compatible way to create an SSLContext that will reload its certificate(s) if they change on disk.

Some approaches I've come up with:

1. Make a dynamic trust manager/trust store, then plug that into the Netty SSLContextBuilder. Could use this is a starting point https://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/managing-a-dynamic-java-trust-store/, and take some of the code to load the key/cert from [Programmatically Obtain KeyStore from PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501117/programmatically-obtain-keystore-from-pem?rq=1) (Netty’s PEM -> KeyStore logic is not public in the SSLContext class). Upside: works outside Netty too. Downside: complicated and doesn’t reuse Netty’s existing logic to load PEM keys and certs.
2. Add this as a Netty-supported option.

Can anyone point me to a solution, or suggest the best way forward to building one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reloading a java.net.http.HttpClient's SSLContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506869/reloading-a-java-net-http-httpclients-sslcontext)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The answer is: don't do it at this level. Instead, have something outside the Netty stack monitor the cert, and when the cert changes remove the existing SSL handler from the pipeline and replace it with a new one with a SSLContext created from the new cert.

Comment: Yea I have this issue, I am sure as many others. Its a PITA on the java side as it is. Although I found this way back and it may allow bypassing of the keystore. https://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html

Comment: Have you tried out this approach? I tried implementing the exact thing and it doesn't get refreshed.

Comment: Yes, I added code to my Netty pipeline builder that adds the SSL context from a cached location. The context at that location is periodically updated with the latest cert from S3. Been working well so far.