# Send https request in java using .pem file

Tags: java, http, ssl, https, httpclient

I have .pem file containing certificate, private key and trust chain, and .p12 file that I've generated from it using **openssl pkcs12 -export:**

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out file.p12 -in file.pem -inkey file.pem -passin pass:password -passout pass:password`

My PEM file structure:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I'm using this curl request to fetch data from API:

```
curl --cert file.p12:password --cacert file.pem --resolve destinationHost.com:443:100.100.100.100 -H "Content-Type: text/plain" https://destinationHost.com/api
```

I'm trying to implement this request using Java (no matter which library).

Example using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35327982/6247832) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514888/6247832)

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.http.conn.DnsResolver;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        byte[] certAndKey = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.pem"));
        byte[] certBytes = parseDERFromPEM(certAndKey, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "-----END CERTIFICATE-----");
        byte[] keyBytes = parseDERFromPEM(certAndKey, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");

        X509Certificate cert = generateCertificateFromDER(certBytes);
        RSAPrivateKey key  = generatePrivateKeyFromDER(keyBytes);

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(null);
        keystore.setCertificateEntry("alias", cert);
        keystore.setKeyEntry("alias", key, "password".toCharArray(), new Certificate[] {cert});

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());

        KeyManager[] km = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        context.init(km, null, null);

        DnsResolver dnsResolver = new SystemDefaultDnsResolver() {
            @Override
            public InetAddress[] resolve(final String host) throws UnknownHostException {
                if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("destinationHost.com")) {
            /* If we match the host we're trying to talk to,
               return the IP address we want, not what is in DNS */
                    return new InetAddress[] { InetAddress.getByName("100.100.100.100") };
                } else {
                    /* Else, resolve it as we would normally */
                    return super.resolve(host);
                }
            }
        };

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(context, new NoopHostnameVerifier());

        BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(
                RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                        .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                        .register("https", socketFactory)
                        .build(),
                null, /* Default ConnectionFactory */
                null, /* Default SchemePortResolver */
                dnsResolver
        );


        httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connManager);

        CloseableHttpClient client = httpClientBuilder.build();

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://destinationHost.com/api");

        CloseableHttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);

        int statusCode = execute.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        assert statusCode == 200;
    }



    private static byte[] parseDERFromPEM(byte[] pem, String beginDelimiter, String endDelimiter) {
        String data = new String(pem);
        String[] tokens = data.split(beginDelimiter);
        tokens = tokens[1].split(endDelimiter);
        return DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(tokens[0]);
    }

    private static RSAPrivateKey generatePrivateKeyFromDER(byte[] keyBytes) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        return (RSAPrivateKey)factory.generatePrivate(spec);
    }

    private static X509Certificate generateCertificateFromDER(byte[] certBytes) throws CertificateException {
        CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        return (X509Certificate)factory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes));
    }
}
```

But receiving:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:338)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:95)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: @JoeC sorry. This is my first question here.

Comment: @JoeC edited accordingly

Comment: The downvoting was unnecessary. You could simply have asked him to give more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to add the TrustManager to init method of SSLContext. Now everything works.

```
TrustManager acceptAll = new X509TrustManager() {
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
};

context.init(km, new TrustManager[]{acceptAll}, null);
```