# How to do mutual SSL authentication in java

Tags: java, ssl, mutual-authentication

I want to do mutual SSL authentication using java code but I didn't get success I have `key.pem` and `cert.pem` file to do authentication I have tried it with Curl

`curl -X POST -d '{ "Channel": "....}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Auth1: ***" -H "Auth2: ***" -k https://******/webservices/JSON/Default.aspx --cert "cert.pem" --key "Key.pem"`

and it was working fine then I trying to create java program reference [Send https request in java using .pem file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361621/send-https-request-in-java-using-pem-file)
but server returns "CERT_MISSING". I also tried with this https://www.naschenweng.info/2018/02/01/java-mutual-ssl-authentication-2-way-ssl-authentication/ this code creating p12, crt and jks file as above link says but still getting same error "CERT_MISSING".
This is working NodeJS example:

```
var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");

var jsonData = {
    "Channel": ....
}

var options = {
    hostname: "****",
    port: 443,
    path: '/webservices/JSON/Default.aspx',
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: this.TimeOut,
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json',"Auth1": "****","Auth2": "*****"},
    json: true,
    key: fs.readFileSync('Key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
}

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(response)

            req.end();
    });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR:");

    })


req.write(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
req.end();
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need "internediate-cert" file to Concatenate all certificates into one PEM file Like `cat "internediate-cert.pem" "codika_cert.pem" "Key.pem" > full-chain.keycert.pem`
then Generate the PKCS12(.p12) keystore with the alias and password Like `pkcs12 -export -in "full-chain.keycert.pem" -out full-chain.keycert.p12 -name alias -noiter -nomaciter` then use `full-chain.keycert.p12` as KeyStore with password. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to try to recall a few things to perhaps complete your checklist. I can't give a full example. I presume you control both client and server code. Or at least the client code, and full tuning of server config.

0-use wireshark to see what going on.

1-make sure your server side sends the accept-client-cert or requires-client-cert in the serverhello. Curl might be working only because the server isn't "requiring" it, only requesting it.

2-make sure your client cert signer will be trusted by the server. This means sometimes to hack the server's certificate authorities (CA) store if you will be making self-signed client cert when testing.

3-with wireshark, watch ssl/tls dialog and verify both clienthello and serverhello are as expected (mostly if serverhello does request/require client auth and if client even tries to send it). If anything, that is quite educative.

4-write trivial code using jsse tutorials from bottom up. make code kata to see the keystore/castore are there, contains what you expect. Then proceed with secure [server]socketfactory setup, keymanager, trustmanager and hostnameverifier (with or without the dangerous bypass of the later two some people dare suggest). When these 4 pieces are setup, you are 99% done and your ssl/tls socket should work. The few things that could typically still prevent your from a ssl/tls connection are incompatible cipher suite or tls version, or certs with invalid dates. Since you control both client and server, this should not be an issue.

5-once you can trust your client side behavior, you may try to connect to an https server like tomcat or jetty (I dont know what you use) and send a crude GET on the sslsocket with you java client.

6-When that works, now you can pass your sslsocketfactory to many http[s] stack (smtp, httplient, even core jdk httpurlconnection).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. We don't have control of server. so we con't check is it accepting our jks file or not. Can we send pem files directly to the server I have checked with node.js also it is working with nodeJS by directly sending pem file in request.
please find attached nodeJS code for reference

Comment: I have edited my post and added NodeJS example there. please check that also