# How to connect to a docker daemon listening to ssl/tls connections over <HostVMIP>:2376 using Java?

Tags: java, rest, ssl, docker, https

I have a docker daemon running in a VM and listening to secure connections from outside world over HOST_VM_IP:2376 . I have generated the **ca.pem** , **cert.pem** and **key.pem** as per docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/ 
and started the docker daemon using them.

I am able to curl to the vm endpoint:port to make the REST api calls.

I want to use the **ca.pem** , **cert.pem** and **key.pem** and create a secure connection using JAVA .

**How do I use these 3 files to create a https client in java to make rest api calls.**

I want to specify the contents of those 3 pem files in a textbox in UI, which i will retrieve programmatically at runtime !!

Thanks!!

Comment: This might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146624/apache-httpclient-and-pem-certificate-files

Comment: I want to specify the contents of the files in UI textboxes . I will be retrieving them programmatically at runtime to create the connection  !!

Comment: I don't really see how that makes the answer i linked irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

Just suggestion and I think the answer also.

Why you want to create your own connector while there is great docker client module for java?

Consider using [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) it is very easy to setup:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.docker-java</groupId>
      <artifactId>docker-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and configure with many different ways:

- System Environment
- System properties
- properties on class path
- programmatic

You want to create DockerClient [programatically](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java#programmatic) at runtime so you will need something like:

```
DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
    .withDockerHost("tcp://my-docker-host.tld:2376")
    .withDockerTlsVerify(true)
    .withDockerCertPath("/home/user/.docker/certs") // here is the place where your certificates are located
    .withDockerConfig("/home/user/.docker")
    .withApiVersion("1.23")
    .withRegistryUrl("https://index.docker.io/v1/")
    .withRegistryUsername("dockeruser")
    .withRegistryPassword("ilovedocker")
    .withRegistryEmail("dockeruser@github.com")
    .build();
DockerClient docker = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config).build();
```

BTW, [CertificateUtils](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/core/util/CertificateUtils.java#L42) also checks whether certificates in defined path exist and there are many great features for docker and it is already implemented.

```
public static boolean verifyCertificatesExist(String dockerCertPath) {
  String[] files = {"ca.pem", "cert.pem", "key.pem"};
  boolean result = true;
  for (String file : files) {
     File path = new File(dockerCertPath, file);
     result &= path.exists();
  }
  return result;
}
```